# In Jquery how can do Jquery function after render HTML function finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have `ul li` like this:

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is, if I load data from JSON file and render to that `<ul>`:

```
RenderHTML : function(){
  var txt = "";
  $.each(item, function(i, items){
    txt += '<li>'+items.name+'</li>' 
  });
  $('#test').append(txt);
}
```

Sorry for my English, I means: After  RenderHTML function has finished, I  wants to invoke a callback, where I could then use another function to create pagination links for the lists (with all the new items added from the json)

Comment: Please rewrite your question from scratch. There is no way anyone know what you are asking here.

Comment: We need to know a) what does the JSON look like ... b) what the expected output should be (what json key/value goes where) ....

Comment: I think what the user is trying to ask is. After his RenderHTML function has finished, he basically wants to invoke a callback, where he could then use another function to create pagination links for the lists (with all the new items added from the json) 

I think anyway, that's how I interpreted it

Comment: Yes my opinion lik TommyBs:D thanks TommyBs

Answer (score 1):

Based on interpretation I created a little test page which executes what I believe the user wants. The "var items" is where the user will need to load in their wanted JSON.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var items = [{name:'test1'},{name:'test2'}]

$(function(){
  var txt = "";
  $.each(items, function(i, item){
    txt += '<li>'+item.name+'</li>' 
  });
  $('#test').append(txt);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="test"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```